# UML, <<extending>> and <<including>> from the same use case

Tags: uml, use-case, include

[image: UML Diagram]

This is a use case diagram about the enrollment of students at a university. There are several flaws in it, and I have to find them.

I am wondering what is happening when you get to use case "Choose course". Yes, you will also have to "Enroll", but what happens if you choose a course that is not available? You will extend the use case, "Course not available", but will you still enroll the course that isn't available? It seems to me like you will.

It would have been different if the association between "Choose Course" and "Enroll" was an extend, because then you only sometimes would enroll in the course, most likely only when it is available.

I am assuming the same logic applies to the "Log-in" use case and the "Student not Identified" use case. You can choose a course without being identified as a student.

Comment: "Student not identified" and "course not available" are not really suitable for a use case diagram.  Those things belong in some other diagram, like a flowchart.  Red Beard's use case diagram below is much better.

Comment: are you sure you dont want another type of diagram e.g. activity maybe? you seem to be trying to show state transitions?

Comment: Again: Log In is no use case but a constraint that can be applied to use cases. Besides that: don't start functional decomposition with UCs. Recommended read: Bittner/Spence about use cases.

Comment: Intersting that a robot pushes this up the queue again. The OP is pretty much already overseas.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure to understand your use case diagram. What do you want to express? I guess that a Student can "Enroll a Course". To do so, he needs to "Pay fees", "Choose a Course", and "Log-In" right? So the includes links are in the other ways as depicted below.
[image]

Now to really need to express tha fact that a course is not available? Or a user is not logged? If yes what for?

Comment: Pretty late for a comment, but your includes go the wrong way around.

Comment: You are right. I updated it. Thanks !!!

Comment: I'm always preaching that "Log in" is no use case but a constraint. Seems that's stuck too deeply in people's minds. Alas, the rest is ok.